# trying to write data from a textbox to a newly created field in the Order table of NopCommerce v2.65

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, e-commerce, nopcommerce

I am trying to write data from a textbox as below to a newly created field in the Order table of a sql server database. I am using **NopCommerce 2.65**
I am at the moment pulling my hair out trying to find an answer on the internet.

```
Nop.Web/Themes/CorpWear2/Views/ShoppingCart/OrderSummary.cshtml
```

Thanks in advance for any help given.

```
AddInfo:@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.OrderEnquiry, new { style = "width:465px; height:45px" })#
```

The following code is what I have achieved by reading data from the Field and displaying 
it on the *OrderSummary.cshtml* page.

```
1.Created Field: OrderEnquiry in Order Table
2.Nop.Core.Domain.Orders.Order.cs
#region Properties
public virtual string OrderEnquiry { get; set; }
3.Nop.Data.Mapping.Orders.OrderMap.cs
this.Property(o => o.OrderEnquiry).HasMaxLength(255).IsOptional();
4.Nop.Web.Themes.CorpWear2.Views.Order.Details.cs
http://localhost:2619/orderdetails/7697
@Html.Widget("orderdetails_page_bottom")
<div class = "order-enquiry">
OrderEnquiry:@Html.Raw(Model.OrderEnquiry)#
</div>
5.Nop.Web.Controllers.OrderController.cs
#region Utilities
[NonAction]
protected OrderDetailsModel PrepareOrderDetailsModel(Order order)
{
// Alteration
model.OrderEnquiry = order.OrderEnquiry;
6.Nop.Web.Modules.ShoppingCart.ShoppingCartModule.cs
public string OrderEnquiry { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to create a new checkout attribute, if my assumption is correct you do not need to add new field just add a checkout attribute  ( admin-> catalog -> attributes -> checkout attributes)

If you still need to add new property try to follow [Update an existing entity](http://www.nopcommerce.com/docs/73/updating-an-existing-entity-how-to-add-a-new-property.aspx)